Difficulty Achieving Stable Alternate Phase Synchronization (APS) in Metronome Synchronization Experiment
I am doing an experiment regarding the synchronization of two metronomes. My setup consists of two metronomes and a platform and cans. I place the platform on top of the cans and the metronomes on top of the platform. There are two types of synchronization the metronome can produce alternate phase synchronization(APS) (when the phase difference between my metronomes are 180 degrees) and in phase synchronization(when the phase difference between my metronomes are 180 degrees).From numerical modals we know that if the frequency difference between these two metronomes are exactly zero there is 50-50 chance for APS and IPS(If we choose random initial conditions). But when frequencies start to differ the probability for APS increase and reach 1.After further frequency difference the metronomes fail to synchronize.
The metronomes synchronize due to the motion of the platform so more motion means better synchronization. I initially tried plastic and glass platforms and found it was pretty hard for synchronization to occur. I think this is due to the weight of my glass and plastic platform which restrict the amplitude of oscillation of the platform. Then I tried cardboard and thermocol platforms. I found the thermocol platforms gives a larger amplitude of oscillation, due to its low weight.
I also tried different types and number of cans. I started using 2 cans, but since the thermocol is pretty weak its wobbles during the oscillations which I thought was reducing the energy going towards the amplitude of oscillation. So I introduced 4 cans to provide more support.(but this itself might increase the inertia and reduce the oscillation of the platform.)
I am using a software called tracker to find the frequencies exactly. I have managed make the frequency difference between the metronomes as low as order $10^{-4}$. Based on the numerical analysis this probability is enough to produce equal probabilities of APS and IPS. But I am only getting stable IPS. Even if APS is achieved its not stable and can be seen for only 30 seconds or so and goes back to IPS. What am I doing wrong? I Have noticed that small difference in the arrangement of cans can affect the chances of getting even IPS.I am thinking the cans are the problem. Is there any other creative way to replace the cans? I am open to any help I can get.

have a look at Synchronization of Metronomes this 14-year-old page and YouTube demonstration will give you some answers in the text.
